# Maps from $SO(3)$ to $S^1, S^2$, and $S^1 \times S^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

I am looking for continuous maps between the special orthogonal group of $3\times 3$ matrices and the unit circle, unit sphere, and their product ($S^1$, $S^2$, $S^1 \times S^2$, respectively). Any hints as to what I should fix/look for? The maps need not be injective/surjective.

Comment: Constant is OK?

Comment: yes, but non-trivial maps would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a hint. You know that every row and column is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ of length one.